# MVC4 Routing With Folder and Sub Folder Names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

**We are Working on MVC4 and Finding it difficult to manage all the folders under view only. 
my controller structure is changes as below and i have also aligned my view accordingly**

- Controllers(namespace : myclass.controllers)

  - AccountController.cs(namespace : myclass.controllers)
  - Admin(Folder namespace : myclass.controllers.Admin)

    - Dashboard.cs(namespace : myclass.controllers.Admin)
    - Reports(Folder namespace : myclass.controllers.Admin.Reports)
- Views

  - Accounts
  - Admin

    - Reports

**Please Suggest the RouteConfig For this Structure.**

Answer (score 2):

Although convention is the preference for MVC, you are allowed to "decouple" your view paths from what MVC expects. BUT, then you must explicitly give the path of the view to the controller.

So, instead of doing this : return View(model)

You supply the complete path to the view: return("~/Views/MyCustomerFolder/Report1.cshtml",model)

The route config shouldn't be affected. Look at using AREAs to better organize the structure of your MVC project.